# Find similar images by shape and related to it

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

I'm new to machine learning, image recognition etc. I'm developing an application in which, when I upload an image, it should list images in my database according to similarity and later by relation.

For eg. When i upload an image of a waterbottle with a sipper cap, it should list waterbottles with a sipper cap first, followed by other water bottles, followed by lunch boxes, kitchenware etc.(Images from my database).

For this application, is machine learning necessary? Which modules do you suggest to implement this? I prefer to learn and develop myself and avoid using APIs. Can u suggest a learning path for me? Thank you!!